# ASP.NET Core and JSON Web Tokens - Custom claims mapping

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt

ASP.NET Core has it's own mapping to standard claims. [Read this](https://mderriey.com/2019/06/23/where-are-my-jwt-claims/) and take a look at this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs)

I am using Azure AD, NET5.

The problem is that unique_name get mapped to name and if you are real lucky you will end up with two name claims. For me one with my full name and one with my email.

Code for handling duplicated name claims.

```
string email = null;
var nameClaims = httpCtx.User
                        .FindAll(x => x.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Name))
                        .Where(x => x.Value.Contains("@")).ToList();
if(nameClaims.Any())
{
  email = nameClaims.First().Value;
}
```

Code for adding auth.

```
services  
 .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
 options.Authority = openIdConnectOptions.Authority;
 options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = openIdConnectOptions.ValidIssuer;
 options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = openIdConnectOptions.ValidAudiences;
 options.MapInboundClaims = true;
});
```

If you set MapInboundClaims = false then there will be now mappings and all claims will keep there names.
This solves my problem with duplicated name claim but also break how roles are mapped an used in ASP.NET Core.

I would like to keep the default mapping and add my own for the types I know get wrongly mapped.
Or remove all mappings and add the missing parts to make roles work again.

Comment: You can manipulate the static [`JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.defaultinboundclaimtypemap?view=azure-dotnet) dictionary to customise the default mapping.

Comment: "[...] but also break how roles are mapped an used in ASP.NET Core". This is not related to ASP.NET Core, but to which claim a ClaimsIdentity uses by default to determine which role(s) the user belongs to. If you turn off claim mapping, the "role" claims will stay as-is, so you need to instruct the JWT stack to use that claim instead. You can do this with `options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";`. You can do the same with `NameClaimType` if the name mapping is also broken.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with.
Now claim names are not changes. Except for roles. I needed to add MS claim names to get roles to work in my policy mapping.

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;

namespace EmployeeTrading.Server.Extensions
{
    public static partial class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddBearerAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services,
            OpenIdConnectOptions openIdConnectOptions)
        {
#if DEBUG
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
#endif
            // // https://mderriey.com/2019/06/23/where-are-my-jwt-claims/
            // https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/a301921ff5904b2fe084c38e41c969f4b2166bcb/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs

            services
                .AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", o =>
                {
                    o.Authority = openIdConnectOptions.Authority;
                    o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = openIdConnectOptions.ValidIssuer;
                    o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = openIdConnectOptions.ValidAudiences;
                    o.MapInboundClaims = false;
                    o.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
                });

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```